# Getting "H2OResponseError: ModelBuilderErrorV3" "Missing training frame" when training with GLM http_status = 412

Tags: python, h2o, glm, http-status-code-412

Using the python library, I'm training a GLM as part of a H2O ensemble that I'm creating:

(relevant snippet from script):

```
from h2o.estimators.glm import H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator
estimator = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(
            nfolds=5, keep_cross_validation_predictions=True,
            fold_assignment='Modulo',
            solver='COORDINATE_DESCENT',
            alpha=[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
            lambda_=[
                319.3503133509223, 198.32195498930167,
                123.16129399741205, 76.48525015768037,
                47.49863615273374, 29.49745776759067,
                18.318421016404645, 11.376049799889723,
                7.064719657533626, 4.387310597042732,
                2.7245942101039184, 1.6920191642541902,
                1.050772567007053, 0.652547566186266,
                0.4052430939917762, 0.2516628269534475,
                0.1562868791824152, 0.09705679976763945,
                0.060273916981481074, 0.03743112359966524,
                0.023245361909429163, 0.01443576356615629,
                0.008964853743724, 0.005567326056432596,
                0.003457403802078978, 0.0021471063360513445,
                0.0013333894107306014, 0.0008280574142025093,
                0.0005142376830786764, 0.0003193503133509216],
            lambda_search=True, nlambdas=30, max_iterations=300,
            objective_epsilon=0.0001, gradient_epsilon=1.00E-06,
            link='identity', lambda_min_ratio=1.00E-06,
            max_active_predictors=5000, obj_reg=1.03E-05,
            max_runtime_secs=342.6666667)

estimator.train(x=predictors, y=response, training_frame=df_h20)
```

I run this training in parallel with other dataframes containing different combinations of features

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(
                    max_workers=len(persona_list)) as executor:
                    future_list = {
                        executor.submit(
                            AVM_H2O.regressor,
                            area,
                            [x[1]],
                            dataset,
                            h20_mms_GB,
                            timestamp,
                            datestring,
                            S3_upload_bucket,
                            logfile,
                            54320 + x[0]): x for x in enumerate(persona_list, 1)}
                    for future in futures.as_completed(future_list):
                        future.result()
```

I do this many times over many different datasets and I only seemingly randomly run in to this error. When I try to recreate the error I can't seem to do so.

The full error message is:

```
H2OResponseError: ModelBuilderErrorV3  (water.exceptions.H2OModelBuilderIllegalArgumentException):
    timestamp = 1583433807040
    error_url = '/3/ModelBuilders/glm'
    msg = 'Illegal argument(s) for GLM model: GLM_model_python_1583433786455_5.  Details: ERRR on field: _train: Missing training frame: py_7_sid_b8c3'
    dev_msg = 'Illegal argument(s) for GLM model: GLM_model_python_1583433786455_5.  Details: ERRR on field: _train: Missing training frame: py_7_sid_b8c3'
    http_status = 412
    values = {'messages': [{'_log_level': 1, '_field_name': '_train', '_message': 'Missing training frame: py_7_sid_b8c3'}, {'_log_level': 5, '_field_name': '_balance_classes', '_message': 'Not applicable since class balancing is not required for GLM.'}, {'_log_level': 5, '_field_name': '_max_after_balance_size', '_message': 'Not applicable since class balancing is not required for GLM.'}, {'_log_level': 5, '_field_name': '_class_sampling_factors', '_message': 'Not applicable since class balancing is not required for GLM.'}, {'_log_level': 5, '_field_name': '_tweedie_variance_power', '_message': 'Only applicable with Tweedie family'}, {'_log_level': 5, '_field_name': '_tweedie_link_power', '_message': 'Only applicable with Tweedie family'}, {'_log_level': 5, '_field_name': '_theta', '_message': 'Only applicable with Negative Binomial family'}], 'algo': 'GLM', 'parameters': {'_train': {'name': 'py_7_sid_b8c3', 'type': 'Key'}, '_valid': None, '_nfolds': 5, '_keep_cross_validation_models': True, '_keep_cross_validation_predictions': True, '_keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment': False, '_parallelize_cross_validation': True, '_auto_rebalance': True, '_seed': -1, '_fold_assignment': 'Modulo', '_categorical_encoding': 'AUTO', '_max_categorical_levels': 10, '_distribution': 'AUTO', '_tweedie_power': 1.5, '_quantile_alpha': 0.5, '_huber_alpha': 0.9, '_ignored_columns': None, '_ignore_const_cols': True, '_weights_column': None, '_offset_column': None, '_fold_column': None, '_check_constant_response': True, '_is_cv_model': False, '_score_each_iteration': False, '_max_runtime_secs': 342.6666667, '_stopping_rounds': 3, '_stopping_metric': 'deviance', '_stopping_tolerance': 0.0001, '_response_column': 'price_lr', '_balance_classes': False, '_max_after_balance_size': 5.0, '_class_sampling_factors': None, '_max_confusion_matrix_size': 20, '_checkpoint': None, '_pretrained_autoencoder': None, '_custom_metric_func': None, '_custom_distribution_func': None, '_export_checkpoints_dir': None, '_standardize': True, '_useDispersion1': False, '_family': 'gaussian', '_rand_family': None, '_link': 'identity', '_rand_link': None, '_solver': 'COORDINATE_DESCENT', '_tweedie_variance_power': 0.0, '_tweedie_link_power': 1.0, '_theta': 1e-10, '_invTheta': 10000000000.0, '_alpha': [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0], '_lambda': [319.3503133509223, 198.32195498930167, 123.16129399741205, 76.48525015768037, 47.49863615273374, 29.49745776759067, 18.318421016404645, 11.376049799889723, 7.064719657533626, 4.387310597042732, 2.7245942101039184, 1.6920191642541902, 1.050772567007053, 0.652547566186266, 0.4052430939917762, 0.2516628269534475, 0.1562868791824152, 0.09705679976763945, 0.060273916981481074, 0.03743112359966524, 0.023245361909429163, 0.01443576356615629, 0.008964853743724, 0.005567326056432596, 0.003457403802078978, 0.0021471063360513445, 0.0013333894107306014, 0.0008280574142025093, 0.0005142376830786764, 0.0003193503133509216], '_startval': None, '_calc_like': False, '_random_columns': None, '_missing_values_handling': None, '_prior': -1.0, '_lambda_search': True, '_HGLM': False, '_nlambdas': 30, '_non_negative': False, '_exactLambdas': False, '_lambda_min_ratio': 1e-06, '_use_all_factor_levels': False, '_max_iterations': 300, '_intercept': True, '_beta_epsilon': 0.0001, '_objective_epsilon': 0.0001, '_gradient_epsilon': 1e-06, '_obj_reg': 1.03e-05, '_compute_p_values': False, '_remove_collinear_columns': False, '_interactions': None, '_interaction_pairs': None, '_early_stopping': True, '_beta_constraints': None, '_plug_values': None, '_max_active_predictors': 5000, '_stdOverride': False}, 'error_count': 2}
    exception_msg = 'Illegal argument(s) for GLM model: GLM_model_python_1583433786455_5.  Details: ERRR on field: _train: Missing training frame: py_7_sid_b8c3'
    stacktrace =
        water.exceptions.H2OModelBuilderIllegalArgumentException: Illegal argument(s) for GLM model: GLM_model_python_1583433786455_5.  Details: ERRR on field: _train: Missing training frame: py_7_sid_b8c3
        water.exceptions.H2OModelBuilderIllegalArgumentException.makeFromBuilder(H2OModelBuilderIllegalArgumentException.java:19)
        hex.ModelBuilder.trainModelOnH2ONode(ModelBuilder.java:304)
        water.api.ModelBuilderHandler.handle(ModelBuilderHandler.java:64)
        water.api.ModelBuilderHandler.handle(ModelBuilderHandler.java:17)
        water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:471)
        water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:301)
        water.api.RequestServer.doPost(RequestServer.java:227)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
        org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
        org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:427)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        water.webserver.jetty8.Jetty8ServerAdapter$LoginHandler.handle(Jetty8ServerAdapter.java:119)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:984)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1045)
        org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)
        org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:236)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
        org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    parameters = {'__meta': {'schema_version': 3, 'schema_name': 'GLMParametersV3', 'schema_type': 'GLMParameters'}, 'model_id': None, 'training_frame': None, 'validation_frame': None, 'nfolds': 5, 'keep_cross_validation_models': True, 'keep_cross_validation_predictions': True, 'keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment': False, 'parallelize_cross_validation': True, 'distribution': 'AUTO', 'tweedie_power': 1.5, 'quantile_alpha': 0.5, 'huber_alpha': 0.9, 'response_column': {'__meta': {'schema_version': 3, 'schema_name': 'ColSpecifierV3', 'schema_type': 'VecSpecifier'}, 'column_name': 'price_lr', 'is_member_of_frames': None}, 'weights_column': None, 'offset_column': None, 'fold_column': None, 'fold_assignment': 'Modulo', 'categorical_encoding': 'AUTO', 'max_categorical_levels': 10, 'ignored_columns': None, 'ignore_const_cols': True, 'score_each_iteration': False, 'checkpoint': None, 'stopping_rounds': 3, 'max_runtime_secs': 342.6666667, 'stopping_metric': 'deviance', 'stopping_tolerance': 0.0001, 'custom_metric_func': None, 'custom_distribution_func': None, 'export_checkpoints_dir': None, 'seed': -1, 'family': 'gaussian', 'rand_family': None, 'tweedie_variance_power': 0.0, 'tweedie_link_power': 1.0, 'theta': 1e-10, 'solver': 'COORDINATE_DESCENT', 'alpha': [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0], 'lambda': [319.3503133509223, 198.32195498930167, 123.16129399741205, 76.48525015768037, 47.49863615273374, 29.49745776759067, 18.318421016404645, 11.376049799889723, 7.064719657533626, 4.387310597042732, 2.7245942101039184, 1.6920191642541902, 1.050772567007053, 0.652547566186266, 0.4052430939917762, 0.2516628269534475, 0.1562868791824152, 0.09705679976763945, 0.060273916981481074, 0.03743112359966524, 0.023245361909429163, 0.01443576356615629, 0.008964853743724, 0.005567326056432596, 0.003457403802078978, 0.0021471063360513445, 0.0013333894107306014, 0.0008280574142025093, 0.0005142376830786764, 0.0003193503133509216], 'lambda_search': True, 'early_stopping': True, 'nlambdas': 30, 'standardize': True, 'missing_values_handling': 'MeanImputation', 'plug_values': None, 'non_negative': False, 'max_iterations': 300, 'beta_epsilon': 0.0001, 'objective_epsilon': 0.0001, 'gradient_epsilon': 1e-06, 'obj_reg': 1.03e-05, 'link': 'identity', 'rand_link': None, 'startval': None, 'random_columns': None, 'calc_like': False, 'intercept': True, 'HGLM': False, 'prior': -1.0, 'lambda_min_ratio': 1e-06, 'beta_constraints': None, 'max_active_predictors': 5000, 'interactions': None, 'interaction_pairs': None, 'balance_classes': False, 'class_sampling_factors': None, 'max_after_balance_size': 5.0, 'max_confusion_matrix_size': 20, 'max_hit_ratio_k': 0, 'compute_p_values': False, 'remove_collinear_columns': False}
    messages = [{'__meta': {'schema_version': 3, 'schema_name': 'ValidationMessageV3', 'schema_type': 'ValidationMessage'}, 'message_type': 'ERRR', 'field_name': 'train', 'message': 'Missing training frame: py_7_sid_b8c3'}, {'__meta': {'schema_version': 3, 'schema_name': 'ValidationMessageV3', 'schema_type': 'ValidationMessage'}, 'message_type': 'TRACE', 'field_name': 'balance_classes', 'message': 'Not applicable since class balancing is not required for GLM.'}, {'__meta': {'schema_version': 3, 'schema_name': 'ValidationMessageV3', 'schema_type': 'ValidationMessage'}, 'message_type': 'TRACE', 'field_name': 'max_after_balance_size', 'message': 'Not applicable since class balancing is not required for GLM.'}, {'__meta': {'schema_version': 3, 'schema_name': 'ValidationMessageV3', 'schema_type': 'ValidationMessage'}, 'message_type': 'TRACE', 'field_name': 'class_sampling_factors', 'message': 'Not applicable since class balancing is not required for GLM.'}, {'__meta': {'schema_version': 3, 'schema_name': 'ValidationMessageV3', 'schema_type': 'ValidationMessage'}, 'message_type': 'TRACE', 'field_name': 'tweedie_variance_power', 'message': 'Only applicable with Tweedie family'}, {'__meta': {'schema_version': 3, 'schema_name': 'ValidationMessageV3', 'schema_type': 'ValidationMessage'}, 'message_type': 'TRACE', 'field_name': 'tweedie_link_power', 'message': 'Only applicable with Tweedie family'}, {'__meta': {'schema_version': 3, 'schema_name': 'ValidationMessageV3', 'schema_type': 'ValidationMessage'}, 'message_type': 'TRACE', 'field_name': 'theta', 'message': 'Only applicable with Negative Binomial family'}]
    error_count = 2
```

Because I can't reproduce the error, I'm struggling to get an idea of what's causing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is raised [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-core/src/main/java/hex/ModelBuilder.java#L1182); in particular, in your case, the object `py_7_sid_b8c3` is valued with `null`. That's a (Java, not Python despite the name) H2O object, which should encode the H2O frame passed for the training. Objects live within each node, I faced a similar issue and I discover in my case that one node was crashing for memory issues. Of course, it could be anything else which does not allow the cluster to get the H2O frame. In anycase, I suggest to inspect the stdout and the stderr logged by the JVMs which run the H2O cluster. They are generally stored in `/tmp`, their paths are shown at the moment you init the H2O cluster. Generally in the Java stacktrace more info is logged.

**UPDATE**: I was able to trigger again this issue in another case

1. import of a CSV file into an H2O frame
2. drop of a column, like `df = df.drop('col')`
3. run then the train of an estimator: `estimator.train(x=predictors, y=response, training_frame=df)` (with `predictors` valued with a list of columns which refer to the feature of the model, and `response` valued with the label needed for the training)

I think the error was due because H2O frames as Python objects refer to a Java object in the H2O backend: probably here after the `drop` there was a pending reference to a null vector, which triggered the exception. Maybe there was some race condition because not all the time the exception was raised.

I finally solved simply passing the proper list of usable features in the `predictors` variable. But as said in my previous comment, the main insight arrived looking at JVMs logs.

Comment: Perfect! The key fix for me here was to keep the data as a pandas dataframe all the way until it was time to pass the data to the JVM for training. Only then did I convert it to a H2OFrame. Since doing this I'm yet to encounter this problem again.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not about `R`, but I've been consistently having the same error in `R`. If any other `R` user stumbled on this thread looking for a solution:

I restarted h2o

```
h2o.shutdown()
h2o.init(enable_assertions = FALSE)
```

and immediately recreated my h2o training data

```
train.hex <- as.h2o(train_set)
tune.hex <- as.h2o(tune_set)
test.hex <- as.h2o(test_set)

trainh2o <- h2o.assign(train.hex, key = "train")
tuneh2o <- h2o.assign(tune.hex, key = "tune")
testh2o <- h2o.assign(test.hex, key = "test")

#Set up variable names 
xnames = setdiff(names(trainh2o, y = trainh2o$outcome)
yname = "outcome"
```